# How to set db structure for users - groups (vast amounts of data)

Tags: mysql, database

I want to write an app where users can join groups (chat rooms). Simple enough.
Being optimistic as I am, I'm already thinking on the sweet times when I'll have 100,000,000 users, each user engaged in say 50 groups.
I'll be working in Java + Hibernate + MySQL (later Oracle?) on server side.

I have a users table with userId, and groups table with groupId.
Now I can write a straight forward table: participants (groupId, userId) - but it will be 500,000,000 rows long.

Or I can do dual mapping with strings: 
Each user has a text value - list of comma separated group Ids (easy to fetch user's group list)
and each group has a text value - list of comma separated user Ids (easy to fetch group's user list)

The disadvantage is basically keeping the data twice and having to maintain it twice (and I can already see myself staying up at night looking for the bugs there)

What is the best approach here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In a relational database... relational data.  comma separated lists are NOT relational.

Comment: any time you think a comma delimited field is the answer - take a break and come back later, because you're wrong.

Comment: OK. So 500M records (integers&boolean fields) will work, assuming I'm indexing correctly?

Comment: and you have enough hardware behind it.